# Jenkins - How to bind a url to a java method which returns json string?

Tags: java, rest, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am practicing developing a jenkins plugin. And I want to send an ajax request with some cookies in front end for back end processing and then receive some json response to continue processing my front end logic. Is it possible for me to bind a url to a back end java method with parameters like `StaplerRequest` and `StaplerResponse` and simply get the returned json from the method as my response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around, I found a site [introducing how Jenkins stapler works.](http://stapler.kohsuke.org/reference.html) Particularly, the **action method** might be helpful for me

According the document I found:

> **Action Method**
>
> If url is of the form "/fooBar/...." and node has a public "action" method named doFooBar(...), then this method is invoked.

to retrieve a json response,
In front end,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./someUrl/",
}).done(doSomethingOnData(data));
```

In back end, define a corresponding action method:

```
public void doSomeUrl(StaplerRequest request, StaplerResponse response) {
    Cookie[] myCookies = request.getCookie();
    doSometingBasedOnCookies(myCookies);
    response.setStatus(200);
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    String myJson = getJson();
    response.getWriter().print(myJson);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create simple Rest Method which consume nothing but response back in JSON, something like this

```
@POST
@Path("/somemethod")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CommonResponseBean somemethod() {
    return response(); // return CommonResponseBean, this will automatically converted into json using jackson
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think Jenkins has its own stapler to handle the url mappings. I am not developing a simple rest application...